# AMP - Overflow element must be defined for resizable frames

Tags: amp-html

I am getting the following validation error in the console when implementing an `amp-iframe`:

```
<amp-iframe width="600" height="140" layout="responsive" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals allow-popups allow-forms" resizable src="https://mydomain/page.html"></amp-iframe>
```

> Overflow element must be defined for resizable frames

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution.

The amp documentation states that an `amp-iframe` must have `overflow` child element, therefore:

```
<amp-iframe width="600" height="140" layout="responsive" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals allow-popups allow-forms" resizable src="https://mydomain/page.html">
<div overflow tabindex=0 role=button aria-label="">Read more...</div>
</amp-iframe>
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just removed the `resizable` attribute as it wasn't needed and `layout="responsive"` was enough. Check out the [layouts page](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-html-layout/layouts_demonstrated/?format=websites).